# Improving postgres sub query using coalesce

Tags: sql, postgresql

Picture this: Two tables, cases and case_messages. A case can have any number of messages or none. One of these messages can be the final answer in a case. I now want to return a list of cases with a bool column that tells me whether there is a final answer or not. If there are no messages at all for a case the query should return "false". Only if there is at least one related message in case_messages where isfinalanswer = true should the query return true. I managed to get this working with coalesce and a sub query, but it feels super ugly:

```
SELECT cases.id, cases.title,
COALESCE((SELECT isfinalanswer FROM case_messages WHERE caseid = cases.id ORDER BY isfinalanswer DESC LIMIT 1), false) AS hasfinalanswer,
FROM cases;
```

How can I improve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using `exists`:

```
SELECT c.id, c.title,
       (exists (SELECT 1 FROM case_messages cm WHERE cm.caseid = c.id and isfinalanswer = true)
       ) as hasfinalanswer
FROM cases c;
```

I don't know if you will think that this is less ugly.

I should add that for performance (which is not mentioned in the question), you would want an index on `case_messages(caseid, isfinalanswer)`.  With such an index, this is likely to be the most performant solution.

Comment: The downvote wasn't mine. +1 from me. Good suggestion about the index. I don't think we have one on that table.

Comment: @ypercube . . . (These comments make more sense on my answer.)  The two queries should produce the same output.  I don't know what you mean by the queries "being the same", but the `order by` is not necessary with `exists`.

Comment: Yeah, I was wrong. I hadn't noticed that the `ORDER BY` in the subquery was using the same column (`isfinalanswer`) as the `SELECT`. By the way, I didn't get this notification - but saw this by accident. It would only reach me if I had already made a comment here.

Comment: @ypercube . . . That last point is interesting.  I thought that by including your name, you would get notified.

Comment: No, only previous commenters will (and the OP of course.) You can try it and see that auto-complete will work (for ypercube or Henrik) here but not for Clodoaldo.

Comment: I am marking this as the answer since the code is a lot more concise than the other answer. I am not noticing any perceivable difference in performance between the two alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

A correlated subquery (a query on the select list) can be nasty on performance. Do a `left join` and `distinct on`

```
select distinct on (c.id)
    c.id, c.title,
    coalesce(cm.isfinalanswer, false) as hasfinalanswer
from
    cases c
    left join
    case_messages cm on cm.caseid = c.id
order by 1, 3 desc
```

In this case `coalesce` can be replaced by `is true`

```
    cm.isfinalanswer is true as hasfinalanswer
```

---

Edit: To avoid the cost of the `order by` required by `distinct on` do a pre aggregation

```
select id, title, coalesce(isfinalanswer, false) as hasfinalanswer
from
    cases c
    left join (
        select caseid as id, bool_or(isfinalanswer) as isfinalanswer
        from case_messages
        group by 1
    ) cm using (id)
```

Comment: A correlated subquery is not necessarily awful for performance.  It depends on a number of factors.  And, `distinct on` requires sorting all the data, which is also a performance hog.

Comment: @ypercube . . . The original query has an `order by` in the subquery, not in the outer query.

Comment: @Gordon An alternative without `distinc on`